# Data from 2 Tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops

I have a table ORDERS and a table MASTERBASE.

Now I would like to output everything from the table Orders

AND

the data that corresponds to the booknumber(s) for each order.

There can be several booknumbers for each ORDER

The code only returns 1 order with book details, but there are several orders ..

```
 <?
    require "../LAB MANU/DbConnect.php";
    mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8');


        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE id > 0");

        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($raw_results);


            if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

                while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){


                    echo $results ["id"];
                    echo "<br /><br />";
                    echo $results ["firstname"];
                    echo "<br /><br />";
                    echo $results ["name"];
                    echo "<br /><br />";



                    $ids = $results ["booknumbers"];




                    require "../LAB MANU/DbConnect.php";
                    mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8');

                    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MASTERBASE_VOLLEDIG WHERE BOEKNUMMER IN ({$ids})");

                    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($raw_results);



                    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

                    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
                                        // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

                    echo $results ["BESCHRIJVING"];

                            }}}}

                        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should change variable names 
$raw_results to another one.Because this variable get a new value inside the loop.